# Allow an editor to change the author

Tags: user-roles, author, permissions

I am using WordPress multi user and have a set of users set up as Editors who wish to ghost write for another user who is an author.

How can they change who the author of the posts is without the author having to review each post?

I can only seem to edit it under quick edit if I am logged in as the author.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use 'register_post_type' ? If yes, you can add on supports parameters => 'author' ?